# Is it possible to have different password policies for different users?

Tags: administration, security, passwords

Can I have a certain profile to have a password change policy of 1 year, and other profiles (or the rest) as change every 60 days?

I know you can set it for the entire organization, I need to specify users/profiles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Winter'15, one can set password policy and session time out properties per profile. Below is link to the release notes pertaining to the same.

http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter15/release-notes/rn_forcecom_security_profile_additions.htm

Answer (score 10):

Nope. The closest you can get is this

Create a permission set which has "Password Never Expires", assign this to the users which have a 1 year policy. Then set a reminder for the admins to expiry users with that permission set each year.

Then just implement your 60 day policy as is.

Comment: It's a totally painful oversight in my opinion.

Comment: Things to note with Password Policies: 1. Shortening a Password Policy will change the password expiration date for Users. 2. Lengthening the password expiration time will not change this. Users password will expire with the old timeframe. 3. Setting password never expires on their profile will update immediately.

Answer (score 10):

If you look into single sign on options with SAML and use Salesforce as a Service Provider you could enforce differing password policies on your identity provider as the authentication will be done there, not at Salesforce's end.

But out of the box, it can not be done.

Comment: i believe this answer has been superseded by answers below.

Answer (score 1):

Winter 15 new functionality : password policy on profile level !

Comment: Can you share a link to it?\

Comment: This may be a correct answer but please provide a bit more context and perhaps a link to the documentation

Answer (score 1):

[Link to the release notes for winter 15 to set password policy at the profile level](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/api_cti/release-notes/rn_forcecom_security_profile_additions.htm)

Comment: While links are useful they don't always last forever.  It's helpful to give the important information from your link as well so that your answer remains valid if the link changes.